# How to give stacklabels in stacked column chart in rails using chartkick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, charts, stacked, chartkick

[image]I am trying to give data labels to a column chart in rails using [chartkick](https://github.com/ankane/chartkick). The stacklabels are the data appearing on the stacks. For eg. the numbers shown on the coloured columns

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @mudasobwa, I have changed the problem description.

Comment: What do you call data labels? What is written under the x-axis is the key for the value in the hash `column_chart` accepts as an input.

Comment: The stacklabels are the data appearing on the stacks. For eg. the numbers shown on the coloured columns in the image